# Trying to loop through an array with condition and return a new array. But can't figure out the syntax

Tags: javascript

```
    export const updateClientsWithStudies = ((studyResponses: StudyResponse[], clients: Client[]) => {
      const studiesArray: Study[] = []
      const studies = convertStudyResponses(studyResponses)
      const clientsWithStudies: Client[] = clients.map((clientYears) =>{
         if(clientYears == stu)
     })
     studiesArray.push(clientsWithStudies)
    })
```

// The logic is: /**

- call the convert () before going to the -> loop through clients -> loop through the years -> condition (clientYearId == carrier_year_id)
  -> push to studies[] */**strong text**
  I figured the loop out with for loop. but don't know the syntax in map(). here is the code:

```
      export const updateClientsWithStudies = ((studyResponses: StudyResponse[], 
         clients: Client[]) => {
        const studiesArray: Study[] = []
        const studies = convertStudyResponses(studyResponses)
        const clientsWithStudies: any[] = () => {
          for (let i = 0; i < clients.length; i++){
            // tslint:disable-next-line: prefer-for-of
            for (let j = 0; j < clients[i].clientYears.length; j++){
              // tslint:disable-next-line: prefer-for-of
              for (let l = 0; l < studies.length; l++){
                  if (clients[i].clientYears[i].year === 
       studies[i].carrierYearID){
                  const st: Study[] = []
                  st.push(studies[i])
                  return st
                }
               }  
              }
             }
            }
          studiesArray.push(clientsWithStudies)
         }
        )
```

Comment: Your question isn't very clear, but I think you probably are looking for the `.filter()` method rather than `.map()`. Filter allows you to only include those elements in the input array, based upon some condition that returns true to keep false to leave out. Filter returns an array with the results included/removed. So there is not need to `.push()` anything. [Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: I am running a loop on clients[] which as one element clientYears[]. So now I was trying to run the second loop on the clientYears[] to get the years (elements). Trying to figure out the syntax here

Comment: Data transformation questions should always include the input and expected output of the transformation process. Please edit your question to include both. That will make it much easier to solve your problem with clarity.

Comment: I think i figured out the loop in for loop. but need to know to write it in map(). Any suggestions for advance map() in javaScript parctice?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a filter instead of map.

```js
const nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];

const result = nums.filter(num => num < 5);

console.log(result);
```